# JavaScript-powered website needs large amount of memory but profiler doesn't give hints

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to find out why my website (using JavaScript, including jQuery and the Google Maps API v2) needs more than 400 MB of memory for a single tab.

What I've done so far:

- Tried in both Firefox and Chrome, same problem
- Checked Chrome's task manager before creating a route on the map and afterwards

  - Before: 28 MB tab process memory (31 MB in "private memory", 13 MB "shared memory")
  - After: 550 MB tab process memory (557 MB in private memory, also 13 MB shared memory)
- Made heap snapshots with Chrome developer tools

  - Snapshots before and after are very similar, both showing around 12 MB of heap objects

So here's my question: What exactly do the terms "private/shared memory" mean - does it have something to do with stack variables? How do I debug the huge "private" memory usage? Don't really care which browser I use for debugging.

Edit: Unfortunately, the memory problem arises when I create a GMaps route in my application, which doesn't seem to work correctly with IE - so I'm kind of restricted to Firefox/Chrome.

Edit 2: I have tracked down the problem without any tools (I'm still interested in tools if somebody knows one). The problem occurs when I call `someGPolylineInstance.insertVertex(0, point)` where point is a lat/lng point from the "dblclick" event. Everytime I insert a point (I commented out everything else that happens in the double-click handler), memory usage goes up by ~1 MB in Chrome. Could this be a problem with the Maps API?

---

So as I can't put up my whole website, I extracted a minimal example which shows the problem. Currently I can reproduce the problem on Chrome 10. Adding a route point by double-clicking adds roughly 0.5 MB of memory usage, while adding 50 points at once needs less memory. Please try and tell me whether you experience the same (simply open the example as "file://"):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;oe=utf-8&amp;key=open_me_as_file_so_that_no_key_is_necessary"></script>
        <script>
            function init()
            {
                map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {mapTypes : [G_NORMAL_MAP],
                                                                        draggableCursor : "crosshair"})
                line = new GPolyline(new Array(), "#0090EE", 2, { clickable: false, geodesic: false })
                map.addOverlay(line)
                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(49, 9), 12)
                map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl())
                map.disableDoubleClickZoom()

                GEvent.addListener(map, "dblclick",
                    function(overlay, clickedPoint)
                    {
                        if(!overlay)
                            line.insertVertex(0, clickedPoint)
                    }
                )
            }

            lat = 49
            lng = 9
            function doSomething()
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
                {
                    lat += 0.05
                    lng += 0.03
                    line.insertVertex(0, new GLatLng(lat, lng))
                }
                document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = line.getVertexCount() + " points"
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init();">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
        <div id="debug"></div>
        <button onclick="doSomething();">Add 50 points</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to try [DynaTrace Ajax Edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/)

Comment: Can you post a link to your site?

Comment: @josh: Sorry, private site which is not on the Internet. I want to learn how to debug it myself ;)

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks for the suggestion. Downloading the Firefox version right now...

Comment: @AndiDog good luck with it - I've only used the IE version but it's pretty cool

Comment: Sadly my website does not work correctly with IE, and DynaTrace for Firefox doesn't show any information on memory usage. Are there any tools available for Chrome?

Comment: Be aware that v2 of the GMaps API has been deprecated.  Try using [v3](http://code.google.com/intl/nl/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Directions) instead.

Comment: @Martijn: Migrated my application to v3 now, but still see the same issue. My first thought - cached uncompressed map tiles - can't be correct because the problem occurs even if I stay on the same map region.

Comment: @Martijn: Oh wait, forgot to remove the v2 script and some old methods. Now it looks like the problem is resolved. Memory consumption is a lot lower and Chrome's GC cleans up several megabytes once a minute or so. Looks good - but I'll check again with other browsers.